# How to configure bootstrap-sass on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm building a Rails application and I decided to use bootstrap and sass.

I follow the guide on the github page:

```
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
```

So, now i have my gem installed ('bootstrap-sass', 'sass-rails'), my application.css (now application.sass) looks like this:

```
1 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
2 @import "bootstrap";
```

My application.js file looks like this:

```
1 // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
2 // listed below.
3 //
4 // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
5 // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
6 //
7 // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
8 // compiled file.
9 //
10 // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
11 // about supported directives.
12 //
13 //= require jquery
14 //= require jquery_ujs
15 //= require turbolinks
16 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
17 //= require_tree .
```

And then the guide pretty much ends.
The problem is that I don't have bootstrap in my application(I can't see it anywhere in the page by viewing the source) and I do not know how to use sass.
What should I do next? Did I miss something?

Comment: do you have anything else in your stylesheets?

Comment: or have you written any code since installing?

Comment: I have written some code (a couple of models, some controllers...some views...) but nothing about stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it should all be ready to go but you will have to start writing some code that it can apply. Perhaps test it with this. In your application.html.erb file under body put the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="main">
            <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </div>
```

then in the css file try this

```
#container {
    .main {
            width:600px;
            h1 {
                    color: $red;
            }
    }
```

Make sure you have restarted your server after the bundle install.
The list of bootstrap variables can be found here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

Comment: if you read further down the github gem page under usage it says how to import bootstrap into sass e.g @import "bootstrap";

Comment: Yes, if you chek the first post, I added the line: @import "bootstrap"; in my application.sass file!

But still if I write something like: <div class='row'> and then i use some col div nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I wrote all the import tag between the html

```
<title>
```

tag instead of the

```
<head>
```

tag.